# Python 2.7; called command is getting cut off

Tags: python, git, python-2.7

```
 gitLog = 'git log {0}..{1} --pretty=format:"%an %h %ad %d %s" --date=short --topo-order --no-merges {2}'.format(tag1, tag2, FILE_NAME)
```

When I run the script it appears to be cutting off and is only running git log {0}. Looks like everything after the {0} gets dropped to a new line.

```
Invoking: git log HEAD
..14.4.15.1 --pretty=format:"%an %h %ad %d %s" --date=short --topo-order --no-merges      file.xml
```

Comment: Is there any chance that ```tag1``` includes a new line character? (```"\n"```)

Comment: You probably have a newline ('\n`) in `tag1`

Comment: Is there a better way to do the following                                                                          
    tag1 = parsedOutput[0]
    tag1 = tag1.rstrip('\n')

Comment: You could do it all in one go. And you don't need to specify an argument for ```rstrip()```.  So it could be ```tag1 = parsedOutput[0].rstrip()```

Answer (score 0):

you should maybe trim all your parameters to be sure.

If they come from a list (cf. your comment), you can:

```
params = [p.strip() for p in params]
```

if not, just manually trim each of them.